# Python BST not working

Tags: python, binary-search-tree

I'm new to Python thus the question,this is the implementation of my my BST

```
class BST(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None
        self.size = 0

    def add(self, item):
        return self.addHelper(item, self.root)

    def addHelper(self, item, root):
        if root is None:
            root = Node(item)
            return root

        if item < root.data:
            root.left = self.addHelper(item, root.left)
        else:
            root.right = self.addHelper(item, root.right)
```

This is the Node object

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
```

This is my implmentation of **str**

```
def __str__(self):
    self.levelByLevel(self.root)
    return "Complete"



 def levelByLevel(self, root):

        delim = Node(sys.maxsize)
        queue = deque()
        queue.append(root)
        queue.append(delim)
        while queue:
            temp = queue.popleft()
            if temp == delim and len(queue) > 0:
                queue.append(delim)
                print()
            else:
                print(temp.data, " ")
                if temp.left:
                    queue.append(temp.left)
                if temp.right:
                    queue.append(temp.right)
```

This is my calling client,

```
def main():
    bst = BST()
    bst.root = bst.add(12)
    bst.root = bst.add(15)
    bst.root = bst.add(9)

    bst.levelByLevel(bst.root)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Instead of the expected output of printing the BST level by level I get the following output,

```
9  
9223372036854775807
```

When I look in the debugger it seems that the every time the add method is called it starts with root as None and then returns the last number as root. I'm not sure why this is happening.
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the following, you can see that `bst.root` in `None` after the second call to `add()`:

```
>>> bst.root = bst.add(12)
>>> bst.root
<__main__.Node object at 0x7f9aaa29cfd0>
>>> bst.root = bst.add(15)
>>> type(bst.root)
<type 'NoneType'>
```

Your `addHelper` isn't returning the `root` node. Try this:

```
def addHelper(self, item, root):
    if root is None:
        root = Node(item)
        return root

    if item < root.data:
        root.left = self.addHelper(item, root.left)
    else:
        root.right = self.addHelper(item, root.right)

    return root
```

And then it works as expected:

```
>>> bst.root = bst.add(12)
>>> bst.root = bst.add(15)
>>> bst.levelByLevel(bst.root)
(12, ' ')
()
(15, ' ')
(9223372036854775807, ' ')
>>> bst.root = bst.add(9)
>>> bst.levelByLevel(bst.root)
(12, ' ')
()
(9, ' ')
(15, ' ')
(9223372036854775807, ' ')
```

Comment: Yup I just managed to figure that  out too. The code still has a bug, it's still printing one node with the sys.maxsize but I'll sort that hopefully. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Modified by levelByLevel code to `def levelByLevel(self, root):

        delim = Node(sys.maxsize)
        queue = deque()
        queue.append(root)
        queue.append(delim)
        while queue:
            temp = queue.popleft()
            if temp == delim:
                print()
                if len(queue) > 0:
                    queue.append(delim)

            else:
                print(temp.data, end=" ")
                if temp.left:
                    queue.append(temp.left)
                if temp.right:
                    queue.append(temp.right)`

Answer (score 1):

If the `root` argument of your `addHelper` is `None`, you set it to a newly-created `Node` object and return it. If it is not, then you modify the argument but return nothing, so you end up setting `bst.root` to `None` again. Try the following with your code above — it should help your understanding of what your code is doing.

```
bst = BST()

bst.root = bst.add(12)
try:   
    print(bst.root.data)
except AttributeError:
    print('root is None')

# => 12
# `bst.addHelper(12, self.root)` returned `Node(12)`,
#     which `bst.add` returned too, so now `bst.root`
#     is `Node(12)`

bst.root = bst.add(15)
try:   
    print(bst.root.data)
except AttributeError:
    print('root is None')

# => root is None
# `bst.addHelper(15, self.root)` returned `None`,
#     which `bst.add` returned too, so now `bst.root`
#     is `None`.


bst.root = bst.add(9)
try:   
    print(bst.root.data)
except AttributeError:
    print('root is None')

# => 9
# `bst.addHelper(9, self.root)` returned `Node(9)`,
#     which `bst.add` returned too, so now `bst.root`
#     is `Node(9)`
```

So you should do two things:

1. make you `addHelper` always return its last argument — after the appropriate modifications —, and
2. have your `add` function take care of assigning the result to `self.root` (do not leave it for the class user to do).

Here is the code:

```
def add(self, item):
    self.root = self.addHelper(item, self.root)
    self.size += 1    # Otherwise what good is `self.size`?

def addHelper(self, item, node):
    if node is None:
        node = Node(item)
    elif item < node.data:
        node.left = self.addHelper(item, node.left)
    else:
        node.right = self.addHelper(item, node.right)
    return node
```

Notice that I changed the name of the last argument in `addHelper` to `node` for clarity (there already is something called `root`: that of the tree!).

You can now write your `main` function as follows:

```
def main():
    bst = BST()
    bst.add(12)
    bst.add(15)
    bst.add(9)

    bst.levelByLevel(bst.root)
```

(which is exactly what @AaronTaggart suggests — but you need the modifications in `add` and `addHelper`). Its output is:

```
12  

9  
15  
9223372036854775807
```

The above gets you to a working binary search tree. A few notes:

1. I would further modify your `levelByLevel` to avoid printing that last value, as well as not taking any arguments (besides `self`, of course) — it should always print from the root of the tree.
2. `bst.add(None)` will raise an error. You can guard against it by changing your `add` method. One possibility is

   ```
   def add(self, item):
       try:
           self.root = self.addHelper(item, self.root)
           self.size += 1
       except TypeError:
           pass
   ```

   Another option (faster, since it refuses to go on processing `item` if it is `None`) is

   ```
   def add(self, item):
       if item is not None:
           self.root = self.addHelper(item, self.root)
           self.size += 1
   ```
3. From the point of view of design, I would expect selecting a node from a binary search tree would give me the subtree below it. In a way it does (the node contains references to all other nodes below), but still: `Node` and `BST` objects are different things. You may want to think about a way of unifying the two (this is the point in @YairTwito's answer).
4. One last thing: in Python, the [convention for naming things](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions) is to have words in lower case and separated by underscores, not the camelCasing you are using — so `add_helper` instead of `addHelper`. I would further add an underscore at the beginning to signal that it is not meant for public use — so `_add_helper`, or simply `_add`.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the `BST` object basically only to hold a root `Node` and the `add` function doesn't really operate on the `BST` object so it's better to have only one class (`BtsNode`) and implement the `add` there. Try that and you'll see that the `add` function would be much simpler.
And, in general, when a member function doesn't use `self` it shouldn't be a member function (like `addHelper`), i.e., it shouldn't have `self` as a parameter (if you'd like I can show you how to write the `BtsNode` class).

I tried writing a class that uses your idea of how to implement the `BST`.

```
class BstNode:
    def __init__(self):
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.data = None

    def add(self,item):
        if not self.data:
            self.data = item
        elif item >= self.data:
            if not self.right:
                 self.right = BstNode()
            self.right.add(item)
        else:
            if not self.left:
                 self.left = BstNode()
            self.left.add(item)
```

That way you can create a `BST` the following way:

```
bst = BstNode()
bst.add(13)
bst.add(10)
bst.add(20)
```

The difference is that now the `add` function actually operates on the object without any need for the user to do anything. The function changes the state of the object by itself.

In general a function should do only what it's expected to do. The `add` function is expected to add an item to the tree so it shouldn't return the root. The fact that you had to write `bst.root = bst.add()` each time should signal that there's some fault in your design.

Comment: You sound fairly knowledgeable about this topic, maybe add a few examples to help clarify your descriptions?

Comment: @XanderLuciano i can add my implementation of the class would that help?

Comment: Certainly! Examples are great help :)

Comment: Python cares about indentation. Please fix you code.

Answer (score -1):

Your add method probably shouldn't return a value. And you most certainly shouldn't assign the root of the tree to what the add method returns.

Try changing your main code to something like this:

```
def main():
    bst = BST()
    bst.add(12)
    bst.add(15)
    bst.add(9)

    bst.levelByLevel(bst.root)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```